# why is it when i place my textview at the bottom of my background bits of the text dissappear into the back background?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I have a basic background and a textview i wish to place at the bottom of the background but when the textview reaches a certain level it starts to disappear into the background the further down i place the textview in xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/main_background" >
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="537dp"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the textview with the code i have pasted above is only showing the top half of the text TOUCH SCREEN TO START. the bottom half of the text has disappeared into my background. Just to be clear I have not moved the textview out of my background it is still in the area of my background for those of you who are thinking i have placed the textview outside my background area. So why does my textviews text disappear the further down i put the textview?

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0):

Use marginBottom inplace of margin top then it will work fine...

```
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Remove** `android:layout_marginTop="537dp"` and **add** `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

**margin** is the reason for that if you seen this layout in 250*250 screen it will not display it take 537dp from top.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to place text view at the bottom.It will then look like this

[image: Text view at the bottom]